# How to create a new variable merging 2 dichotomous Variables?

Tags: r

Im writing about how parents tweet about their children. My Dataset consists of a metric variable (score in emotions after sentiment analysis) and 2 dichtomous varibales (sex of the child: "son", daughter, sex of the parent: "female", "male").

Now i want to create a new categorial variable called "combination". So i get mother/daughter, mother/son, father/daughter, father/son for creating a boxplot mit means and sd (consisting of 4 groups). 
Does anybody have a idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

`interaction` is specifically meant for cases like this. It does a little bit more than paste: the result is a factor with all possible combinations of x and y as levels -- for example, if there is no "father/daughter" combination in the data, this will still be a level of the resulting factor by default (this can be turned out by setting `drop = TRUE`):

```
with(df, interaction(parent, child))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# example dataset
df <- data.frame(
    score  = runif(100, 1, 10),
    child  = sample(c("son", "daughter"), 100, replace=TRUE),
    parent = sample(c("mother", "father"), 100, replace=TRUE)
)

# boxplot of 4 child*parent combinations
boxplot(score ~ child:parent, data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to name the axis? i want "group" for the x-axis (beneath the combinations mother/daughter and so on) and "Emotion-score" on the y-axis. you would be of great help. im kind of stuck with this problem...

Comment: Add `xaxt="n"` as an argument to `boxplot` so that no x-axis is printed.  Then add your own x-axis with `axis(side=1, at=1:4, labels=c("what", "ever", "you", "want"))`

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to paste the sex labels together

```
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(parent=c(rep('male',6),rep('female',4)), 
       child=c(rep('son',3),rep('daughter',6),rep('son',1)),
       emotion=sample(1:4,10,replace=T))

d$combination <- paste0(d$parent,'/',d$child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here are great. This is the lazy approach if you want an intermediate step, which will create your `combination` variable for use in other analyses, then try

```
data$combination <- paste(data$parent, data$child, sep = ".")
```